# How to connect sslsocket in android lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, sslsocketfactory

Please guide me how to connect with https socket connection in android lollipop. Previously i was able to connect to https server using X509TrustManager by accepting all certificate. But this method is not working properly in android lollipop. When i read documentation i came to know the authType is changed. Please some one help me, how to successfully connected with https socket in android lollipop. Pls share the steps...

Comment: Whats your error? There should be no difference between the versions.

Comment: Actually i am not getting any error in my log. It just stalls after start handshaking. HandShake not completed. I didnt get any response for handshake complete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861553/since-android-lollipop-5-0-i-am-not-able-to-communicate-to-server-x509trustmana

This is the same issue i am facing. Pls give me some solution...